# How to write a unittest for scheduled apex

Tags: apex, unit-test, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch

I have a scheduler for a callout class. I am trying to write a unittest for my scheduler but do not know how to test the execute part

Class

```
 global class or_guestsSchedulable implements Schedulable{

    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) 
    {        
   or_service.getGuests();
    }    
}
```

Unittest

```
private class or_guestsSchedulableTest {

    private static testMethod void or_guestsSchedulable() {

    Test.startTest();
        Datetime dt = Datetime.now().addMinutes(1);
        String CRON_EXP = '0 '+ dt.minute() + ' * ' + dt.day() + ' ' + dt.month() + ' ? ' + dt.year();
        or_guestsSchedulableTest.execute('Sample_Heading', CRON_EXP, new  or_guestsSchedulable () );   
        Test.stopTest();
    }
    }
```

Update Unittest

```
private class or_guestsSchedulableTest {

private static testMethod void or_guestsSchedulableMethodTest() {

Test.startTest();
      String jobId = System.schedule('Sample_Heading', CRON_EXP, new or_guestsSchedulable());  
    Test.stopTest();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are struggling with the basic things, You can learn from here:-

1. [Schedule Jobs Using the Apex Scheduler](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/asynchronous_apex/async_apex_scheduled)
2. [Apex Scheduler](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm)

In your case, to schedule it in the test class, the syntax will be like this:-

```
// Schedule the test job
        String jobId = System.schedule('Sample_Heading',
            CRON_EXP, 
            new or_guestsSchedulable());
```

You are doing it in the wrong way.

```
or_guestsSchedulableTest.execute('Sample_Heading', CRON_EXP, new  or_guestsSchedulable () );
```

For Scheduled Apex you must also ensure that the scheduled job is finished before testing against the results. To do this, use startTest and stopTest again around the **System.schedule** method, to ensure processing finishes before continuing your test.

After you implement a class with the Schedulable interface, use the **System.Schedule** method to execute it. The scheduler runs as system—all classes are executed, whether or not the user has permission to execute the class.

> The System.Schedule method takes three arguments: a name for the job,
>   an expression used to represent the time and date the job is scheduled
>   to run, and the name of the class.

For Cron expression, You can use Online tool available which make sure you don't have any error. I think your Cron statement will not work. Use below link to get correct one:-

[Cron Maker](http://www.cronmaker.com/)

Note:- please change your method name **or_guestsSchedulable** in the test class.

**Update:-**  You need to Create one variable where you will store the Cron value which will tell the test class when to schedule the class.

example:-

```
// Seconds Minutes Hours Day_of_month Month Day_of_week optional_year
String CRON_EXP = '20 30 8 10 2 ?';
```

As i told, generate it link i have provided above.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I tried your suggestion but get  CRON_EXP variable does not exist

Comment: get CRON_EXP variable does not exist:- It is an error you got? Can you update your question with the piece of code you tried?

Comment: See: Compile error: Variable does not exist: CRON_EXP. or_guestsSchedulableTest.cls

Comment: Please Update your question with a new piece of code? It is hard to understand why you are getting this error.

Comment: I just updated my question with you suggestion

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way to test a `Schedulable` or `Queueable` class is to, quite simply, *just call the target method*.

There's basically nothing special about the `execute(SchedulableContext ctx)` method. You can call this method yourself, just like any other method that you have visibility to (i.e. it's either `global` or `public`). `SchedulableContext` doesn't contain much information. If you're not using it, then you can simply pass `null` as an argument to this method.

The goal here is to test that your method behaves correctly, not that Salesforce's scheduler does what it's supposed to.

```
or_guestsSchedulable myInstance = new or_guestsSchedulable();

// It's still a good idea to wrap the execution itself within (start|stop)test
Test.startTest();
myInstance.execute(null);
Test.stopTest();
```

Before I leave, don't forget that you should be *making assertions* in your test to verify that your code actually does what you think it does. Assertions are what makes unit tests truly useful. Whatever output your code generates (a return value, inserting/updating/deleting a record, updating the internal variables of a class) should be asserted.